# karate: assist in finding solution for nested if condition in json response. i tried my best to put my question out there

Tags: json, if-statement, karate

I have lengthy json response (350 lines - tend to increase based on inputs) that has 24 source codes + overall status code.

```
business logic implemented as:: 
Overall status code = GREEN if all (24 codes) are GREEN;
RED if any of them is RED;
YELLOW is any of them is YELLOW and none is RED;
```

I have tried this logic step be step as below, also pls suggest me with the minimum lines code to achieve that.

```
    * def result = callonce read('file.feature')

    Then match result.response.StatusCode == 200
    Then match result.response.Message == 'Request Successful'

    * def final = result.response
    * st1 = final.Result[0].ssmCore.missing.status
    * st2 = final.Result[0].ssmCore.zero.status
    * st3 = final.Result[0].ssmCore.sw.status
    * st4 = final.Result[0].ssmCore.bum.status
    * st5 = final.Result[0].ssmComm.missing.status
    * st6 = final.Result[0].ssmComm.zero.status
    * st7 = final.Result[0].ssmComm.sw.status
    * st8 = final.Result[0].ssmComm.bum.status
    * st9 = final.Result[0].ssmmas.missing.status
    * st10 = final.Result[0].ssmmas.zero.status
    * st11 = final.Result[0].ssmmas.sw.status
    * st12 = final.Result[0].ssmmas.bum.status
    * st13 = final.Result[0].ssmris.missing.status
    * st14 = final.Result[0].ssmris.zero.status
    * st15 = final.Result[0].ssmris.sw.status
    * st16 = final.Result[0].ssmris.bum.status
    * st17 = final.Result[0].ssmhist.missing.status
    * st18 = final.Result[0].ssmhist.zero.status
    * st19 = final.Result[0].ssmhist.sw.status
    * st20 = final.Result[0].ssmhist.bum.status
    * st21 = final.Result[0].ssmpr.missing.status
    * st22 = final.Result[0].ssmpr.zero.status
    * st23 = final.Result[0].ssmpr.sw.status
    * st24 = final.Result[0].ssmpr.bum.status

    * def overallStatus = final.Result[0].Sourcestatus

    * def ssmcorestatus = '{st1 == "RED" || st2 == "RED" || st3 == "RED"  || st4 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'
    * def ssmCommstatus = '{st5 == "RED" || st6 == "RED" || st7 == "RED"  || st8 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'
    * def ssmmasstatus = '{st9 == "RED" || st10 == "RED" || st11 == "RED"  || st12 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'
    * def ssmrisstatus = '{st13 == "RED" || st14 == "RED" || st15 == "RED"  || st16 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'
    * def ssmhiststatus = '{st17 == "RED" || st18 == "RED" || st19 == "RED"  || st20 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'
    * def ssmprstatus = '{st21 == "RED" || st22 == "RED" || st23 == "RED"  || st24 == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'


    * def status = '{ssmcorestatus == "RED" || ssmCommstatus == "RED" || ssmmasstatus == "RED"  || ssmrisstatus == "RED" || ssmhiststatus == "RED" || ssmprstatus == "RED" }' ? 'RED' : 'GREEN'

    * print overallStatus
    * print status

    * match overallStatus == status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one line should give you all the statuses !!

```
* def list = $..status
```

And then it is simple:

```
* def reds = karate.filter(list, function(x){ return x == 'RED' })
* def yellows = karate.filter(list, function(x){ return x == 'YELLOW' })
* def overall = reds.length ? 'RED' : ( yellows.length ? 'YELLOW' : 'GREEN' )
```

Comment: thanks for this response, however my karate framework calls feature file from another for response -  * def result = callonce read('file.feature') .. hence * def list = $..status not working as response not defined here. i take result.response.<value> for json parsing. how can i make work $..status for this scenario

Comment: @anonymous that doesn't matter. instead of `response` use any JSON variable e.g. `$myVariable..status`. sounds like you are new to programming, karate and JSON - please take the help of someone

Comment: yes i am new to programming and karate and i have picked up karate tool for api testing automation in my project knowing this challenge. and its working now

Comment: implemented as mentioned here and test failed with error - no step-definition method match found for : def  overall = statusRed.length ? 'RED' : (statusYellow.length ? 'YELLOW' : 'GREEN' ) ... am i missing something here ,?

Comment: @anonymous this works perfectly for me. so now there is nothing anyone can do unless you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: it finally worked. issue was extra space after '=' sign. thanks again :)

Comment: if i want to run these tests for all other result set then I should be using * match each overall = statusRed.................. ? for some reason its not working this way. also would like to know do you have karate tutorial videos to watch and have better understanding before picking up tests please?

Comment: @anonymous please ask a new question if needed. if you are not able to read the docs, it is unlikely any video will help you in my opinion. try this page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Community-News